# App wide accessible Flyout in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a flyout in my app that I use to add additional contacts into the local database. This flyout is declared as a page resource currently, and does exactly what I need it to, however in order to re-use it on a different page I need to copy both the xaml for the flyout and any attatched events to each page that would require using it (there are several places where a contact might need to be added)

Is there a way to globally define a flyout such that I only need to reference it rather than hardcode it each time? I considered using a `ContentDialog` (as that can be defined as its own module) but I don't think that would be the right fit

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't create the Flyout completely in C# code? Then you could simply create somewhere a static method returning the Flyout.

Comment: @schumi1331 its something I considered, but it would mean recreating the layout. I was hoping to reuse the already written XAML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If creating completely in code is not an option you can create a ResourceDictionary with a class in background. First the `Styles.xaml`:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    x:Class="MyClass.Styles"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Flyout x:Key="MyFlyout">
        <!-- my flyout code -->
    </Flyout>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The important thing here is `x:Class`, where the value needs to be the namespace+name of the related class we're creating now (`Styles.cs` in that case):

```
namespace MyClass {
    public partial class Styles {
        public Styles() {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        // my events from flyout
    }
}
```

Make sure that the class is declared as `partial` and calls `this.InitializeComponent()` in the constructor.

Now in your app resources add a reference:

```
<Application
    ...
    xmlns:myClass="using:MyClass">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <myClass:Styles />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Then you can access the Flyout as a static resource, e.g.:

```
<Button Flyout="{StaticResource MyFlyout}" />
```

Comment: I like this approach. I'll give it a try and mark it if it fits