# (XAML UWP) Defining elements, including events for use across multiple pages (c++)

Tags: c++, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, app.xaml

So I'm currently trying to centralize a few elements that I plan on using in several places in my App. For example I have a flyout that serves as a navigation menu in part of the app, but the problem I run into is that I can't set the "Click" event in the application resources where I define it in the App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Flyout x:Key="guided_tour_nav">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button x:Name="home"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Return to Home" Click="home_button_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="water"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Content="The Water Enters"/>
            <Button x:Name="eggs"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Eggs Arrive"/>
            <Button x:Name="pre_hatch"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Pre-Hatching"/>
            <Button x:Name="tanks"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Content="The Tanks"/>
            <Button x:Name="life_support"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Life Support"/>
            <Button x:Name="waste"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Filtering Waste"/>
            <Button x:Name="release"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Content="The Release"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Flyout>
</Application.Resources>
```

I use it in my mainpage.xaml, and a few other pages

```
<Button Flyout="{StaticResource guided_tour_nav}" Content="Jump to Section"/>
```

I'm currently getting the error

`WMC1005    Events cannot be set in the Application class XAML file`

I would like to be able to define the whole element, click events and all, to be referenced wherever I need it without having to redefine the click events for each page. I imagine it must be possible somehow, but I'm completely new to the UWP platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a `Flyout` as a resource in `Application.Resources`, you cannot use it with events, unfortunately.

There are however two alternative solutions.

### Custom User Control

You can wrap the Flyout into a custom XAML user control and then easily reuse anywhere you want.

Right-click your UWP project in *Solution Explorer* and select *Add* - *New item...*. In the dialog select the *XAML* section and there find *User Control* option. Select the desired name (for example `GuidedTourNav`) and click *Add*.

This creates three files - `GuidedTourNavFlyout.xaml`, `GuidedTourNavFlyout.xaml.h` and `GuidedTourNavFlyout.xaml.cpp`. The default type of custom XAML controls is `UserControl`. You need to change this. Open the `GuidedTourNavFlyout.xaml` file and change the root element from `UserControl` to `Flyout`:

```
<Flyout
    x:Class="xxxxxx"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="xxxxxxx"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
</Flyout>
```

Finally, replace the `Grid` inside the `GuidedTourNavFlyout.xaml` code with your flyout contents and create the desired event handler in the code-behind as usual.

Now you can use your custom flyout anywhere. First add a XML namespace declaration to the root element of your page. Replace `MyApp.CustomControls` with the namespace where your custom control lies.

```
xmlns:controls="using:MyApp.CustomControls"
```

And now you can use your flyout anywhere you want using complex property:

```
<Button Content="Hello">
    <Button.Flyout>
        <controls:GuidedTourNavFlyout />
    </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

### Using Resource Dictionary with code-behind

Alternative solution would be to create a Resource Dictionary with code-behind as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41672966/app-wide-accessible-flyout-in-uwp). However this approach seems a bit less clean and I cannot confirm it works in C++.

Comment: Perfect! That was exactly the solution I was looking for. Thanks.